# How can I correctly type-hint a function that uses numpy array operations on either numeric or array-like inputs?

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting

I am trying to learn about type hinting and while it all seems very clear for when a function argument takes on a well-defined data type, I am stuck with how to handle when the argument could be a numeric value OR a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

def square(x: np.ndarray):
    return x**2

num = 9
print(square(num))

arr = np.array([3, 6.31, 9, 8.73])
print(square(arr))
```

This makes mypy say: `error: Argument 1 to "square" has incompatible type "int"; expected "ndarray[Any, Any]"  [arg-type]`

Is it really correct to do the following? It seems very ad hoc, but it makes mypy accept it.

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Union, Any

num_or_array = Union[float, np.ndarray[Any, Any]]

def square(x: num_or_array):
    return x**2

num = 9
print(square(num))

arr = np.array([3, 6.31, 9, 8.73])
print(square(arr))
```

What would be a best practice for this?

Comment: Why call your solution ad hoc? Seems to be the sort of thing that `Union` is there for.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I specify multiple types for a parameter using type-hints?](/q/48709104/4518341) (I'm not a typing expert myself.)

Comment: That other question indicates that you could use `|` as an abbreviation for `Union`